# Check Form Authentication in Client-Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using Form Authentication in my ASP.NET website, I need to check If the user is authenticated before making a callback on client-side, how do i do that using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question to include any relevant code - the more detail you include, the greater your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Add additional info: 1. Do you use ajax or you mean simple callback? 2. if AJAX, what's endpoint?

Comment: I'am registering the callbacks on Page_Load event of the page that inherits ICallbackEventHandler interface, then handle the call inside:
<public void RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)> event after calling them from client-side directly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to define a webmethod to check the session status and then have a .ajax query the method.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSession(string Skey)
{
     return Session[Skey];
}

[WebMethod]
public static string SetSession(string key, string Svalue)
{
     Session[key] = Svaluee;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "website.aspx/GetSessionValue",
            data: '{ key: "CurrentSessionKey" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                  console.log("The Session value is " + data);
            }
});
```

## Update

Read the question wrong. Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear, 
I am not talking about form input validation, please focus when you read posts! I'm talking about User Form Authentication .. 
The Authentication Information stored in an encrypted cookie. am trying to get that cookie expiration time before making a callback method!

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I read that wrong!!! I'm very sorry! I'll update with the correct answer in just a moment

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I am not using ajax calls, I am using     'ICallbackEventHandler' interface, so if I used ajax calls I'll have to change 80% of all my client-side javascript calls.

Comment: Ok, well you might want to update you question with some more details. If you can show how you have tried thus far that would be very helpful.